# Signed, unsigned objects comparison in C : Are there any operators that don't cause conversions ?

Tags: c, type-conversion

From K&R C

A.6.5 Arithmetic Conversions
*Many operators cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way*. The effect is to bring
operands into a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the
usual arithmetic conversions.

In the code below EOF is defined to be -1 which is a signed integral constant, ch should then be converted to int and while loop should be exited eventually, but doesn't seem to happen ! Hence the Qn.

```
int main()
{
 unsigned char ch;
 FILE* fp;
 fp = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
 while((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF)
 {
  printf("%c", ch);
 }
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: just goes in a infinite loop as ch has 255 and EOF -1.

Comment: `ch` should be of int type, since it's return type of `getc`. Broken code don't run, that's expected behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getc` returns an `int` (as it must be able to hold all character values as well as `EOF`).

In your code, you truncate this value to `unsigned char` when you assign it to `ch`. Then you extend it to `int`, which will never result in `EOF`, as -1 truncated becomes 255, which will become the `int` 255.

Comment: +1 a) you beat me to it,b) you included an explanation as to why the comparison was not working.

Comment: Thanks.That clarifies my doubt. Though I still wonder about the statement "Many operators cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way" - Are there any operators that don't cause conversions ?

Comment: I think that would include all binary operators. However, the part of the "common type" clearly does not apply to unary operators like `-x` and `~x`. In additions, things like `sizeof` is, according to the standard, an operator, which does not cause a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile it with GCC with extra warnings, you will get the warning:

```
 warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

This is because of your use of `unsigned char`. Use a normal `char` or `int` for defining `c` and it will work.

Comment: gcc with extra flags is invaluable for this kind of pointers.

Comment: It will not work if `ch` is a `char`, as the legitimate character 0xFF will be converted to -1 and misinterpred as EOF.

Comment: @Lindydancer Works fine for me when testing.

Comment: Did the test file you read really include the character 0xFF? (It simply can't work, as `ch` must be able to hold 257 values, all characters plus `EOF`.)

Comment: @Lindydancer No, but then I don't consider using `getc` for anything in the 128-255 range.

Comment: You can use `char` and have it seem to work but then it will loop indefinitely on systems where the `char` range is the same as `unsigned char`!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `ch` as an `unsigned char`, it should be declared as `int`.  The return type of `getc()` is int.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic conversion *does* occur in the example you cite - the `unsigned char` result of `ch = getc(fp)` is promoted to `int` when it is compared with `EOF`<sup>1</sup>.

This conversion doesn't undo the result of converting -1 to `unsigned char`, though - if that conversion results in 255 (because `unsigned char` is 8 bits), then it will remain as 255 when it is converted back to `int`, since 255 is within the range of `int`.

---

<sup>1. On platforms where `int` cannot represent all the values of `unsigned char` it will be promoted to `unsigned int`, but such platforms are very rare.</sup>